# Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets'

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, websocket, signalr

I develop `asp.net core` app whit `SignalR` and everything is Ok on the localhost. but when I publish the app on a server I receive WebSocket error.

[image: error screenshot]

my test app : http://test.gelimak.ir

Answer (score 1):

Where are you publishing your app?

If it's self-hosted in IIS, you need to enable websockets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enabling-websockets-on-iis

If it's Azure Web App you need to go to the WebSite settings and enable WebSockets.